# Breadth-, Depth-, Preorder-Search in JavaFX Tree

Tags: javafx, treeview

Java's DefaultMutableTreeNode had methods for tree iteration:

- breadthFirstEnumeration();
- depthFirstEnumeration();
- preorderEnumeration();
- postorderEnumeration();

Is there something similar in JavaFX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no corresponding built-in APIs in JavaFX 8.  You can create your own.  There are some examples for depth first search here:

- [TreeView - How to count all children (including collapsed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795514/treeview-how-to-count-all-children-including-collapsed)

Implementing breadth first search is similar to the linked examples, you just use a Queue data structure instead of a stack.

Feature requests to build such functionality into the JavaFX tree structure can be filed at: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com.  The [OpenJFX development team](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Main) might accept a patch which implements these features.