# Iterate TreeView nodes

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm using this code to iterate all TreeView nodes.

```
for (TreeItem<DynamicTreeNodeModel> children1 : children)
                {
                    ObservableList<TreeItem<DynamicTreeNodeModel>> children2 = children1.getChildren();

                    for (TreeItem<DynamicTreeNodeModel> children3 : children2)
                    {
                        ObservableList<TreeItem<DynamicTreeNodeModel>> children4 = children3.getChildren();

                        TreeItem<DynamicTreeNodeModel> tempValue = null;

                        for (TreeItem<DynamicTreeNodeModel> children5 : children4)
                        {
                            // some logic
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Is there any better way to access low level nodes of the TreeView?

Comment: Use a recursive method.

Comment: search for "tree traversal" and then implement the appropriate algorithm for TreeItem

Comment: A couple of related question: [Breadth-, Depth-, Preorder-Search in JavaFX Tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27438738/breadth-depth-preorder-search-in-javafx-tree?) and [TreeView - How to count all children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795514/treeview-how-to-count-all-children-including-collapsed)

Answer (score 5):

You can just use a recursive method, which checks if the current node has children or not. If it has, it calls the same method again, else it prints the  node.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class IterateTree extends Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tree View Sample");        

        TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem<String> ("Inbox");
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            rootItem.getChildren().add(createTreeItem(i));
        }        
        TreeView<String> tree = new TreeView<String> (rootItem);        
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(tree);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
        // print children
        printChildren(rootItem);
    }

    private TreeItem<String> createTreeItem(int num) {
        TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem<String> ("Group " + num);
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            TreeItem<String> item = new TreeItem<String> ("Message" + i);            
            rootItem.getChildren().add(item);
        }
        return rootItem;
    }

    private void printChildren(TreeItem<String> root){
        System.out.println("Current Parent :" + root.getValue());
        for(TreeItem<String> child: root.getChildren()){
            if(child.getChildren().isEmpty()){
                System.out.println(child.getValue());
            } else {
                printChildren(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a utility class for traversing TreeTableView items depth-first. It supports streaming, visitor pattern and iterator pattern.
It may be useful for someone.

```
/**
 * Tree table item walker.
 *
 * @author bvissy
 *
 * @param <T>
 *            The type of the tree items.
 */
public class TreeTableViewWalker<T> {

    /**
     * Utility class to hold a tuple
     */
    public class Tuple<E, F> {
        E first;
        F second;

        public Tuple(E first, F second) {
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;
        }

        public E getFirst() {
            return first;
        }

        public Tuple<E, F> setFirst(E first) {
            return new Tuple<>(first, second);
        }

        public F getSecond() {
            return second;
        }

        public Tuple<E, F> setSecond(F second) {
            return new Tuple<>(first, second);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Tuple [first=" + first + ", second=" + second + "]";
        }
    }

    // The walk state stack
    private Deque<Tuple<TreeItem<T>, Integer>> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();

    /**
     * Initialize the walker.
     *
     * @param tree
     *            The tree to walk
     */
    public TreeTableViewWalker(TreeTableView<T> tree) {
        super();
        if (tree.getRoot() != null) {
            stack.push(new Tuple<>(tree.getRoot(), -1));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return True if has unserved items.
     */
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return !stack.isEmpty();
    }

    /**
     * @return The next tree item in depth walk order. The parent is returned
     *         before any of its children.
     */
    public TreeItem<T> next() {
        if (!hasNext()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("");
        }
        TreeItem<T> nxt = stack.peek().getFirst();
        move();
        return nxt;
    }

    private void move() {
        Tuple<TreeItem<T>, Integer> n = stack.pop();
        ObservableList<TreeItem<T>> ch = n.getFirst().getChildren();
        int idx = n.getSecond() + 1;
        if (ch.size() <= idx) {
            if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                return;
            } else {
                move();
            }
        } else {
            stack.push(n.setSecond(idx));
            stack.push(new Tuple<>(ch.get(idx), -1));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return A stream of all (remaining) items. Note, that the walker could
     *         traverse only once over items.
     */
    public Stream<TreeItem<T>> stream() {
        return StreamSupport.stream(new Spliterator<TreeItem<T>>() {

            @Override
            public int characteristics() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public long estimateSize() {
                return Long.MAX_VALUE;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super TreeItem<T>> action) {
                if (hasNext()) {
                    action.accept(next());
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Spliterator<TreeItem<T>> trySplit() {
                return null;
            }
        }, false);
    }

    /**
     * Walks over the tree and calls the consumer for each tree item.
     *
     * @param tree
     *            The tree to visit.
     * @param visitor
     *            The visitor.
     */
    public static <T> void visit(TreeTableView<T> tree, Consumer<TreeItem<T>> visitor) {
        TreeTableViewWalker<T> tw = new TreeTableViewWalker<>(tree);
        while (tw.hasNext()) {
            visitor.accept(tw.next());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Walks over the tree and calls the consumer for each item value.
     *
     * @param tree
     *            The tree to visit.
     * @param visitor
     *            The visitor.
     */
    public static <T> void visitItems(TreeTableView<T> tree, Consumer<T> visitor) {
        TreeTableViewWalker<T> tw = new TreeTableViewWalker<>(tree);
        while (tw.hasNext()) {
            visitor.accept(tw.next().getValue());
        }
    }

}
```